# fullcalendar viewRender - can't call service angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, service, fullcalendar

I am trying to get events based on the current view. To track 'prev', 'next' clicks and initial display views, I'm using the CalendarOption `viewRender` which returns the full view, and invokes itself every click - which gives a new full view.

Problem is - I cannot call the service from which I'm getting my events from, based on the extracted parameter of the `viewRender` view output.

```
constructor (public eventService: EventService)

calendarOptions = {
  ...
  ...
  eventLimit: true,
  viewRender: function(view) {
    this.eventService.getEvents(view)   // <--- code stops here, error printed at bottom
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.events = response.events;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      );
    console.log(this.events);
  },
  events: this.events,
  ...
  ...
}
```

I'm expecting my service to work and be triggered from within that scenario - on calendar first initializing and each time the 'prev' / 'next' buttons are clicked

currently, the output is

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEvents' of undefined

Is there any other way I can invoke this external command?
I also tried using httpClient directly, but HTTP is also a service which can't be accessed as it seems

Comment: show your EventService

Answer (score 0):

It is now solved

Managed to get access to my service by appending:

`const eventService = this.eventService;`

here:

```
initCalendar() {
  const eventService = this.eventService;
  var events = []
  this.calendarOptions = {
    ...
    ...
    viewRender: function(view) {
    eventService.getEvents(view) // <----- Not accessing with 'this' anymore
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          events = response.events;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      );
    },
    events: events;
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```